# showing hyperlinks using php

Tags: php

Is there a better way to show hyper links in php than using

```
<a href="<?php echo $link; ?>"><?php echo $link; ?></a>
```

Comment: why so particular question? For the tables it's supposed to be another answer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid repeating $link, you can use this:

```
<?php printf('<a href="%1$s">%1$s</a>', $link); ?>
```

Comment: You really ought to call `htmlspecialchars()` on `$link` (yes, both copies).

Comment: @Zack, good point, you could also test before if $link is really a link with something like filter_var($link, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL, FILTER_FLAG_SCHEME_REQUIRED), provided $link is a full URL and not an internal link.

Comment: in fact, you've ended repeating some complex placeholder instead of plain variable :) having code of the same length but less readable, and also spoiling template, making HTML being part of PHP code.

Comment: I'm just answering a simple question, I'm not holding a conference about design patterns, which you seem to be doing EVERYTIME you answer something. And, as a matter of fact, this could be interpreted as a nice micro-templating engine, the first argument of the printf being the template. I guess talking about printf will allow some people to actually LEARN something, even if you don't like it.

Answer (score 2):

```
<a href="<?=$link?>"><?=$link?></a>
```

Comment: Not recommended. It will break on servers with short_open_tag disabled.

Comment: +1 for the echo shorthand, but it's messy and @Capsule is correct

Comment: @Capsule so what? mysql is not recommended too then - It will break on servers with no mysql installed. And mod_rewrite is not recommended too - apache is not the only web-server in the world. After all PHP itself shouldn't be recommended too, there is a possibility of not having it on a particular host. Plain HTML is the only "recommended" then.

Comment: Ah, dear Colonel, my friend, fighting ghosts. Using LONG tags will *never* break. It's a different approach than using MySQL that *might* break. If there was a universal DB or rewriting system, I would recommend using it, yes.

Comment: @Capsule So, that's my point exactly. Using PLAIN HTML will never break. I am sure you're going to uninstall PHP from your host right now.

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel maybe you should uninstall your arrogance or set your php.ini to "humor = On" sometimes, it helps, really.

Comment: using plain html might break (if no webserver installed)

Comment: @Capsule "universal" often means "inconvenient". Say, you can call sqlite such a universal database. I can't see everyone rushes to use it just because of it's availability. Many people prefer non-universal dbms like mysql or postgre. So, it seems there may be another reason, beside availability. I'd call that reason "usability" or "convenience". So, people tend to install a DBMS instead of using highly available plain text file, because database is convenient. Same goes for the short tags. It's just handy.

Comment: @Capsule as for the `humor` setting - are you going to say that you took my advice to uninstall PHP seriously, aren't ya? ;)

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php echo '<a href="'.$link.'">'.$link.'</a>'; ?>
```

Comment: I've been trying to figure out the reasoning for the -1 on this. I have yet to find a good explanation.